# Specflow - Log steps - Given/When /Then steps logging

Tags: selenium-webdriver, specflow

We run nightly regression scripts using Specflow. Was wondering if there is a way to log the specflow console logs to a file. Since it runs at night, we are not sure about the step where the failure occurred.We do use ReportUnit to convert the nunit xml to html. Will be good to have those console logs in the html too.

Answer (score 0):

you can add [hooks](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Hooks) which execute before scenario steps (`[BeforeStep]` and `[AfterStep]`)  and log in there. You can access the `ScenarioStepContext` to get details of the current step.

Comment: @Sam-You meant ScenarioContext,not ScenarioStepContext. I dont see any ScenarioStepContext.If ScenarioContext, how to get the current step being run - passed or errored

Comment: Which version of specflow are you using? ScenarioStepContext was added in v2 to allow you to get the scenario step information so the current step can be logged. I believe it is available as a property on the ScenarioContext object.

Comment: using 1.9 still as specflow + excel not supported in v2.0

Comment: There was an updated version of specrun released a week or so ago. Does that not give you what you want? If you can't use v2 then you can't really do what you want, I know because we wanted to do the same and I had to add the feature to specflow so we could do it, and this was rolled into v2

Comment: @Sam-Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Specrun.Specflow.1.3.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Install-package : Unable to find a version of 'SpecFlow' that is compatible with 'SpecFlow.Plus.Excel 1.2.0 constraint: 
SpecFlow (= 1.9.0)', 'SpecRun.SpecFlow 1.3.0 constraint: SpecFlow (≥ 2.0.0)'.

Comment: There is dependency to update Specrun which in turn needs Specflow 2.0 which is not supported by Specflow + Excel. Hence on Specflow 1.9

Answer (score 0):

A lot has changed with SpecFlow in the last 6 years. Specifically SpecFlow logs each step (along with whether it passes or fails) to the standard output. You can also generate test results files using whichever unit test framework you want. That being said, I did come across a use case where the existing logging that SpecFlow does was not working with Azure DevOps. For my case, I had passing tests, which periodically ran extremely slow. In Azure DevOps release pipelines, a passing test does not get the standard output saved for viewing later. I needed to log the date/time for when a step began, and when it finished.

A before/after step hook using the ScenarioContext object was how I got this logging to work:

```cs
[Binding]
public class Hooks
{
    [BeforeStep]
    public void BeforeStep(ScenarioContext scenario)
    {
        var stepInfo = scenario.StepContext.StepInfo; 
        var stepText = $"{stepInfo.StepDefinitionType} {stepInfo.Text}";

        // log 'stepText' some place
    }

    [AfterStep]
    public void AfterStep(ScenarioContext scenario)
    {
        var stepInfo = scenario.StepContext.StepInfo; 
        var stepText = $"{stepInfo.StepDefinitionType} {stepInfo.Text}";

        // log 'stepText' some place
    }
}
```